# Hidding but using saved passwords in web browser - Use saved passwords in browser without seeing them

Tags: web-browser, chrome, firefox, password-manager, internet-explorer

I have one problem regarding managing passwords in web browsers.

When I save some passwords in Chrome, Mozzila etc, any user can see saved passwords.

I want to have saved passwords, which users can use, but without being able to see those saved passwords and without the option that they will use it on another PC.

Does anyone knows software which could help me with it?

Is there such option in certain web browser already?

Thank you.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Lastpass is free, the extension works in every browser I've tried, and it has Desktop and mobile applications.  I would pay money for it if it weren't free.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.

If I save many passwords in LastPass, can somebody use those passwords for logins in browsers without being able to see them?

I need it because I want to give access to some sensitive data, but I do not want that they be able to login when they are out of the office.

Comment: @Marko Ah, in that case i don’t think you can keep it entirely private.  when password managers fill in the field with asterisks the user can still access the text in the clipboard.